# Oracle audit delete: how to audit what was deleted?

Tags: sql, oracle, audit, sql-delete

Firstly, I am quite new in the oracle audit trail thing. So, I have to audit the actions of a particular user.

My issue is that when I check the dba_fga_audit_trail, I see in the sql_text column that the user ran a delete statement, but I do not know what it is that he deleted. This is what is written in the cell from the sql_text column:

```
DELETE FROM USR WHERE USR_ID = :B
```

Could you please help me find a way to store in the audit trail what line was deleted from a particular table?

Comment: Are you interested in the value of the `B` parameter alone, or also in the rest of the columns of the deleted row?

Comment: I am interested in the rest of the columns of the deleted row. I have the value of the B parameter.

Comment: If I were you I would analyze your online redo log files, this feature is meant for it, audit is to check what user did what without detail

Comment: @zaratustra, I disagree. Fine grained auditing is meant for it.

Comment: @LalitKumarB You might be right, but I always used online redo logs for this purposes. They give me more information.

Comment: @zaratustra I understand whatbyou say, but Oracle does the job for you. So no need to re-invent the wheel. Well, I agree few applications might need user defined auditing.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I don't think this is a re-invention of the wheel, just another approach to solve this task.

Comment: @LalitKumarB thanks for your points, I will try to use audit instead of LogMiner

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table to hold the deleted data, which will have one row per deletion. Then, create a trigger on the USR table which will run after delete. This trigger will select the data you want to audit from the 'dummy' :OLD table, and insert it into your audit table.

Comment: OP is not asking for user defined auditing. Oracle does it for you via audit trail and fine grained auditing. There are lot of options.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that (I worked on an old version of Oracle). Can you post a link as an answer to help? Thanks...

Comment: I posted an answer, it is a simple query to access the fine graimed audit view. I just updated the post so that OP could also view SQL BIND.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that when I check the dba_fga_audit_trail, I see in the sql_text column that the user ran a delete statement, but I do not know what it is that he deleted.

You need to set `audit_trail` to `DBMS_FGA.DB + DBMS_FGA.EXTENDED` sends the audit trail to the `SYS.FGA_LOG$` table in the database and includes SQL Text and SQL Bind.

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = 9998;
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, sal) VALUES (9998, 'Bill', 1);
UPDATE emp SET sal = 10 WHERE empno = 9998;
DELETE emp WHERE empno = 9998;
ROLLBACK;

-- Check the audit trail.

CONN sys/password AS SYSDBA
SELECT sql_text FROM dba_fga_audit_trail;

SQL_TEXT
--------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = 9998
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, sal) VALUES (9998, 'Bill', 1)
UPDATE emp SET sal = 10 WHERE empno = 9998
DELETE emp WHERE empno = 9998

4 rows selected.
```

You can also have a look at Tim Hall's [demo](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2.php).